# How do I classify the Controllers-Actions? in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I’m doing a web project for a College.  I’m would like to use Asp.net MVC for the purpose.
I have designed the database, but I’m not clear about how to classify my Controllers.
Basically, there are three types of users accessing & manipulating the data base.

1. Admin
2. Staff
3. Student

There are a lot of database tables in the project for example:

1. Student profile
2. Staff Profile
3. Student Marksheet
4. Subjects Time table
5. Sports events Table
6. Alumni table
7. and it keeps going on

Now the question is ,

How do I classify the Controllers-Actions?

Should it be based on the User type?
Should it be based on Database?

User type based example:

Localhost:8080/Admin/EditUserProfile
Localhost:8080/Admin/ViewUserProfile
Localhost:8080/Admin/CreateProfile

Localhost:8080/USER/EditUserProfile
Localhost:8080/USER/ViewUserProfile

Localhost:8080/Staff/EditUserProfile
Localhost:8080/Staff/ViewUserProfile

Or it must be based on the Table ?

Localhost:8080/Profile/Edit
Localhost:8080/Profile/View
Localhost:8080/Profile/Create

Localhost:8080/Marksheet/Edit
Localhost:8080/ Marksheet/View
Localhost:8080/ Marksheet /Create

Any help please?---

Comment: You could try using areas..

Comment: An easy way to do this is also assigning roles to the users(if you already have a table on the database which reads for you then you're halfway done) then decorating your Actions or Controllers with `[Authorize(Roles="admin")]` for example

Comment: Controllers should be thought of as groupings of functionality to your site, so if your site has profile functionality, then you would have a Profile controller that handles the profile actions for all users of your site.  You can segment based on security, so students can only create student profiles, etc.